# Unable to install instrument control package in Octave 4.2.0

Tags: installation, serial-port, package, octave

I am trying to install Octave 4.2.0 and a number of packages -- including the instrument control package - in Octave 4.2.0 on a Windows 8.1 laptop with an Intel i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz and 6GB of RAM.

My code uses the serial function to interface to a serial port, so I really need the instrument control package. However, when I tried to install it, I got the following error (I tried both the x86 and x64 version of Octave with the same result):

```
>> pkg install instrument-control-0.2.2.tar.gz
In file included from serial_class_win32.cc:29:0:
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:104:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (eq_serial_serial, serial, serial, ==)
 ^
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:105:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (ne_serial_serial, serial, serial, !=)
 ^
make[1]: [serial_class_win32.o] Error 1 (ignored)
In file included from serial.cc:29:0:
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:104:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (eq_serial_serial, serial, serial, ==)
 ^
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:105:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (ne_serial_serial, serial, serial, !=)
 ^
In file included from serial_class.h:20:0,
                 from serial.cc:29:
serial.cc: In function 'void install_serial_ops()':
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/ops.h:51:13: error: 'oct_binop_eq_serial_serial' was not declared in this scope
    CONCAT2 (oct_binop_, f));
             ^
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/ops.h:32:24: note: in definition of macro 'CONCAT2X'
 #define CONCAT2X(x, y) x ## y
                        ^
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/ops.h:51:4: note: in expansion of macro 'CONCAT2'
    CONCAT2 (oct_binop_, f));
    ^
serial.cc:36:3: note: in expansion of macro 'INSTALL_BINOP'
   INSTALL_BINOP (op_eq, octave_serial, octave_serial, eq_serial_serial);
   ^
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/ops.h:51:13: error: 'oct_binop_ne_serial_serial' was not declared in this scope
    CONCAT2 (oct_binop_, f));
             ^
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/ops.h:32:24: note: in definition of macro 'CONCAT2X'
 #define CONCAT2X(x, y) x ## y
                        ^
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/ops.h:51:4: note: in expansion of macro 'CONCAT2'
    CONCAT2 (oct_binop_, f));
    ^
serial.cc:37:3: note: in expansion of macro 'INSTALL_BINOP'
   INSTALL_BINOP (op_ne, octave_serial, octave_serial, ne_serial_serial);
   ^
make[1]: [serial.o] Error 1 (ignored)
g++: error: serial.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: serial_class_win32.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: [serial.oct] Error 1 (ignored)
In file included from srl_write.cc:23:0:
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:104:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (eq_serial_serial, serial, serial, ==)
 ^
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:105:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (ne_serial_serial, serial, serial, !=)
 ^
make[1]: [srl_write.o] Error 1 (ignored)
g++: error: srl_write.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: serial_class_win32.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: [srl_write.oct] Error 1 (ignored)
In file included from srl_read.cc:28:0:
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:104:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (eq_serial_serial, serial, serial, ==)
 ^
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:105:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (ne_serial_serial, serial, serial, !=)
 ^
srl_read.cc: In function 'octave_value_list Fsrl_read(const octave_value_list&, int)':
srl_read.cc:93:54: warning: 'void (* octave_set_signal_handler(int, void (*)(int), bool))(int)' is deprecated (declared at C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\
octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/sighandlers.h:99): use 'octave::set_signal_handler' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     octave_set_signal_handler(SIGINT, read_sighandler);
                                                      ^
srl_read.cc:101:5: warning: 'install_signal_handlers' is deprecated (declared at C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/sighandlers.
h:114): use 'octave::set_signal_handler' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     install_signal_handlers();
     ^
make[1]: [srl_read.o] Error 1 (ignored)
g++: error: srl_read.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: serial_class_win32.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: [srl_read.oct] Error 1 (ignored)
In file included from __srl_properties__.cc:25:0:
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:104:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (eq_serial_serial, serial, serial, ==)
 ^
serial_class.h:30:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   BINOPDECL (name, a1, a2) \
             ^
serial_class.h:105:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP'
 DEFBINOP_CLASS_OP (ne_serial_serial, serial, serial, !=)
 ^
make[1]: [__srl_properties__.o] Error 1 (ignored)
g++: error: __srl_properties__.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: serial_class_win32.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: [__srl_properties__.oct] Error 1 (ignored)
tcp_read.cc: In function 'octave_value_list Ftcp_read(const octave_value_list&, int)':
tcp_read.cc:110:54: warning: 'void (* octave_set_signal_handler(int, void (*)(int), bool))(int)' is deprecated (declared at C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include
\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/sighandlers.h:99): use 'octave::set_signal_handler' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     octave_set_signal_handler(SIGINT, read_sighandler);
                                                      ^
tcp_read.cc:118:5: warning: 'install_signal_handlers' is deprecated (declared at C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\include\octave-4.2.0\octave\../octave/sighandlers.
h:114): use 'octave::set_signal_handler' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     install_signal_handlers();
     ^
For information about changes from previous versions of the instrument-control package, run 'news instrument-control'.
```

It looks like it can't build the libraries and for sure, after loading the package, if I try:

```
>> which -all serial
>>
```

I get nothing and my code doesn't run because it can't find the `serial` function. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You don't tell which build and installer you are using. The MXE build which you can get from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/ should already include the instrument-control package so I wonder why you are trying to install it manually. Have you downloaded instrument-control-0.2.2.tar.gz separately?

Comment: and from your error message I guess you have to use instrument-control-0.2.3 with Octave 4.2.0

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I did get the installers from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/ (`octave-4.2.0-w32-installer.exe` & `octave-4.2.0-w64-installer.exe`), but I didn't know any packages were included. Until now, I've always had to download and install the packages separately. I'll try again tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure the installer only installs Octave, and none of the packages. I did download `instrument-control-0.2.2.tar.gz` separately, but you're right I need to go up to 0.2.3. I'll report back tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't used windoze the last 15years but the MXE Installer can be built with "--enable-binary-packages" which includes binary forge packages, see http://wiki.octave.org/Windows_Installer but I don't know how John builds the installer. I would suggest you try "pkg list" after a fresh install an see if the packages are there. You still need to "pkg load" them individually. There is also a script "build_packages.m" which helps you to compile and install all forge packages (have a look at the install dir)

Comment: @Andy OK, so I have done a clean install and you were right, the packages are included. However, I found that the `serial` function was still nowhere to be found in the `instrument-control` package after loading it (basically the file `serial.oct` is not where it should be with the other `*.oct` files from the package). The package that came with the installer was also v0.2.2. I downloaded and installed v0.2.3 (had a couple of warnings to do with deprecation) and now I can access the serial function, and my code is running fine. If you want to write up an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Consider writing a bug report and file it on the savannah bugtracker. Please mention where the file serial.oct was, not only " is not where it should be"

Comment: OK will do, thanks. I'll specify the actual location :-)

Comment: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?50185